# Django - can't get list_display to work

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from .models import Feedback
from django import forms

class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = '__all__'

class FeedbackAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = FeedbackForm
    search_fields = ('name', 'category', 'email', 'subject')
    list_display = ('name', 'category', 'email', 'subject', 'is_read')
    list_editable = ('is_read', )

admin.site.register(Feedback)
```

When i run it i don't see the `search_fields`, `list_display`, or `list_editable`.
I also don't get any error messages when i run the server.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually used your FeedbackAdmin class. You need to pass it to `register`.

```
admin.site.register(Feedback, FeedbackAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class FeedbackAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = FeedbackForm
    search_fields = ['name', 'category', 'email', 'subject']
    list_display = ['name', 'category', 'email', 'subject', 'is_read']
    list_editable = ['is_read']

admin.site.register(Feedback,FeedbackAdmin)
```

you didnt register the modeladmin class

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems you didn't register your admin class

```
admin.site.register(Feedback, FeedbackAdmin)
```